# Get multi result from regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to get multi result from Regex, but its not correctly work.

Test string:

```
<div class="row-fluid pybar-row">
    <span class="pybar-label text-left">
        <span class="">Male</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pybar-bars">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <span class="pybar-bar pybar-l" style="">
            <span class="pybar-bg">
                <span style="width:100%">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="pybar-bar pybar-r">
            <span class="pybar-bg">
                <span style="width:78%;">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get only number of style="width:**X**%"

I used this regex:

```
$re = "/<span class=\"pybar-bg\">.*?width:(.*?)%/s";
```

But its only return first number. I want all numbers in string and have this class.

Comment: The poney. Again.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is returning on first match. To match all values use `g` modifier (global match).

```
$re = "/<span class=\"pybar-bg\">.*?width:(.*?)%/sg";
```

Will return:

```
100
78
```

[see demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD9hB4/1)

Comment: That's not the right answer for THIS question: it's tagged `php` where no "g" modifier exists. Instead `preg_match_all()` must be used, as @Nicolai's answer said.

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression works correct. Use `preg_match_all` to extract all matches:

```
$s = <<<HTML
<div class="row-fluid pybar-row">
    <span class="pybar-label text-left">
        <span class="">Male</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pybar-bars">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <span class="pybar-bar pybar-l" style="">
            <span class="pybar-bg">
                <span style="width:100%">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="pybar-bar pybar-r">
            <span class="pybar-bg">
                <span style="width:78%;">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;


$re = "/<span class=\"pybar-bg\">.*?width:(.*?)%/s";
if( preg_match_all( $re, $s, $matches ) ) {
    var_dump( $matches[1] );
}
```

This will output this:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "100"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "78"
}
```